# using F# in matlab by NET.addAssembly function

Tags: .net, matlab, module, f#

I am trying to use F# in matlab by NET.addAssembly  function. I already succeced in a simple sample without module, like the following code

```
namespace test
    type addtwo() =
        class
            member r.f1() = 1
        end
```

But after adding a module in it, I can not use the class in matlab as before

```
  namespace test
     module m1
        type addtwo() =
            class
                member r.f1() = 1
            end
```

It seem the form of NET.addAssembly is Obj = Namespace.Class. So I am wondering how to implement it with a module in the class.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
namespace test
    module m1 =
        type addtwo() =
            class
                member r.f1() = 1
            end
```

But this will compile `m1` as a class and `addtwo` as an inner class and I had problems with Matlab to access the inner class, so if this is also your case I would avoid defining the type inside the module:

```
namespace test
    type addtwo() =
        class
            member r.f1() = 1
        end
    module m1 =
        // your code
```